# Responsive Email - Text breaks up on tablet view

Tags: media-queries, html-email, responsive

I tested the email on desktop and phone, but this is what one of the receivers saw on their tablet. The fonts and `td` are in percents, so I'm not sure why it's doing that. Any idea why this would be happening?

The media query I'm currently using is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
```

I'm thinking that using something like this might fix it:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the complete email code? You might have something off in your `<head>` tags. Also, it's very difficult to use unique fonts or web fonts in emails. No two browsers display them the same.

Comment: The way you're using fonts, you might as well make them part of the graphic. You're not giving yourself a lot of space for the text and you're setting yourself up for failure because custom web fonts are not going to work in Outlook or Gmail, so you'll be reverting to a web-safe font. You could add `white-space: nowrap; word-break: keep-all`, but the fonts will vary wildly by email client.

Comment: Im not sure i understand what you want it to do? A special style targeting the ipad size?